# Is there an inline option that checks for null and blank in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a WebForms application that binds the following result set of errors to a data grid.

```
    SELECT missing.ID, '--Not Found--', '--Not Found--', 'Timeclock ID ('+missing.TimeClock_System_ID+') not found' AS ErrorMessage
    FROM @StudentRecords missing 
    WHERE missing.Registration_ID IS NULL
```

The last column creates a string that later gets bound to the data grid, it usually looks something like this: *"Timeclock ID (1234) not found"*

Problem is that when missing.TimeClock_System_ID == null the whole string breaks and returns "" instead of *"Timeclock ID () not found"*.

**My current workaround is:**

```
ISNULL ( missing.TimeClock_System_ID , 'NULL' )
```

But This breaks down when the value is an empty string.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A case statement When = '' then X Else isnull(...)

Comment: Why does it "break" when an empty string appears?, seems to me like it should give you what you expected: `Timeclock ID () not found`

Comment: Not sure why the whole string returns as null when the value is null, but my colleagues gave me an *oh yes, of course* reaction when I explained it to them. They are under the impression that this is just how TSQL 2008 works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
ISNULL ( nullif(missing.TimeClock_System_ID,'') , 'NULL' )
```

Comment: Awsomesauce! This was what I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `case` statement:

```
case 
 when missing.TimeClock_System_Id is null 
      or missing.TimeClock_System_Id = '' then 'NULL'
 else missing.TimeClock_System_Id
end
```